# Why does Profile.UserLicense.Name return "[object Object]?"

Tags: soql

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_userlicense.htm) indicates that it should return a String. But, when the following query

```
SELECT Id, Name, Profile.UserLicense.Name FROM User
```

is executed in Developer Console, the result returned for that column is `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, I think the dev console can only display parent information, not grandparent information. As such, it shows it as a general object.

i.e. if you run the following, a string will be displayed:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Profile.Name FROM User
```

To get the License name, you can run the following code in the Execute Anonymous window. This shows that the value is being returned, so if you need the values in code, it should work.

```
List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Name, Profile.UserLicense.Name FROM User LIMIT 1];

system.debug(users[0].Profile.UserLicense.Name);
```